# Hardware airplane mode because of broken wifi chip

Tags: wireless, hardware, airplane-mode

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop.
I want to use an external Belkin F7D1101 v1 USB wifi adapter.
Ubuntu recognized it but I can't turn it on. It says I have to press the Hardware switch (which doesn't exist).
I think it's because I have a broken wifi chip in this laptop. So I would like to delete it or go around this problem. Has anyone an Idea how to do this.

Comment: Remove the internal wifi

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  For turning it on, have you tried the function keys.  Many laptops have one of the functions keys assigned to that.  If not, maybe you can find it through the BIOS.